# Best way to make photo of very tall family trees?

Tags: software-recommendations, family-tree-maker, family-tree-builder

I have a family tree of over 100 generations and I am trying share it with my family in print or as a file. Geni.com only allows exporting as many 8×11 papers. I have found a printing service where I can upload images, I just need a way of creating the image. Does anyone know how? No websites I have found allow exporting of a family tree in a size greater than 10 generations. A software maybe?